# How to use date filter for $match inside the laravel mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb

i have two dates $dateFrom = '01-04-2020' and $dateTo = '30-04-2020' and i want to use filter these dates to mongodb database, i using the vuejs for front and backedn is laravel.
    the  mongodb field value is d_creation :01-04-2020 07:54.

```
i am using like this: 
           $date_filter = [
                'd_creation' => [
                    '$gte' => $dateFrom,
                    '$lt' => $dateTo

                ]
            ];
            $condition = [
             '$match' => $date_filter
            ];

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What is your model?

Comment: and what laravel version are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 6.17.1

Comment: my date is saved as string inside mongodb.

Comment: my date is saved inside mongodb is: 
"d_creation" : ISODate("2020-04-03T06:05:08.000Z"),

Comment: db.getCollection('ent').find({"d_creation":{"$gte":ISODate('2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z'),"$lt":ISODate('2020-04-04T00:00:00.000Z')}})

this one is working, but i dont no how to pass or use isodate to laravel

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateFrom = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('01-04-2020'));
$dateTo = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('30-04-2020'));

$condition = [
    '$match' => [
        'd_creation' => [
            '$gte' => $dateFrom,
            '$lt' => $dateTo
        ]
    ]
];
```